# TestKit.expectMsgClass in Akka

Tags: unit-testing, akka, akka-testkit

In the code below:

```
TestKit probe = new TestKit(system); // line 1
ActorRef deviceActor = system.actorOf(Device.props("group", "device")); // line 2

deviceActor.tell(new DeviceManager.RequestTrackDevice("group", "device"), probe.getRef()); // line 3
probe.expectMsgClass(DeviceManager.DeviceRegistered.class); // line 4
assertEquals(deviceActor, probe.getLastSender()); // line 5
```

If I comment out line 4, the test fails. Line 3 is enough to send the message to the actor. So what exactly line 4 is doing?

Comment: Question referenced here too:https://gitter.im/akka/akka

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand what's going on, let's inspect the source code.

Here is the definition of [`getLastSender()`](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/v2.5.11/akka-testkit/src/main/java/akka/testkit/JavaTestKit.java#L117), in which `p` is a `TestProbe`:

```java
public ActorRef getLastSender() {
  return p.lastMessage().sender();
}
```

[`lastMessage`](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/v2.5.11/akka-testkit/src/main/scala/akka/testkit/TestKit.scala#L151) is declared as the following in `TestKit.scala`:

```scala
private[akka] var lastMessage: Message = NullMessage
```

The `lastMessage` variable is mutated in one of two methods, `receiveWhile` and `receiveOne`. The [`expectMsgClass`](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/v2.5.11/akka-testkit/src/main/scala/akka/testkit/TestKit.scala#L507) method calls the latter:

```scala
def expectMsgClass[C](max: FiniteDuration, c: Class[C]): C = expectMsgClass_internal(max.dilated, c)

private def expectMsgClass_internal[C](max: FiniteDuration, c: Class[C]): C = {
  val o = receiveOne(max)
  // ...
}
```

Basically, if you don't call one of the `TestKit`'s built-in assertions (e.g., one of the `expectMsg*` methods) in your test, then `lastMessage` will remain unchanged as a `NullMessage`. If `lastMessage` is a `NullMessage`, then calling `lastMessage.sender` will result in an exception, and `assertEquals(deviceActor, probe.getLastSender());` in your test will fail.

On the other hand, if you do call a built-in assertion such as `expectMsgClass`, then `lastMessage` will be set appropriately, and the sender of `lastMessage` will resolve correctly.

In short, calling `getLastSender()` assumes the use of a `TestKit` assertion. This is implied in the [documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/testing.html#replying-to-messages-received-by-probes) (emphasis mine):

> The probe stores the sender of the last dequeued message (**i.e. after its `expectMsg*` reception**), which may be retrieved using the `getLastSender()` method.